# wp_editor not working in jquery dialog

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have managed to add wp_editor into one of my `textarea` insdie jquery dialog. Now the issue is that it doesn't allow me to switch between `visual` and `text` tabs. Also none of the buttons in the editor are working. Is there any `cdn` or `enqeue` required ?

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php 
        $settings = array(
                'textarea_rows' => 10,
        );
        wp_editor('', 'i_textarea_content',$settings ); ?>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Difficult to say what the problem is with this little information. But one thing that might cause this issue, is if you have multiple wp_editor's on one page. If that is the case, make sure the id (second param) is unique.

Comment: I couldn't provide more information because it is the only part that i have wanted. I have only a single wp_editor. I haven't included any cdn or something like that.

Comment: This works fine outside the dialog.@JeffreyvanRossum

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors? What version of WordPress are you using, because in older versions you couldn't use underscores in the id (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor#Notes).
Also, are you maybe moving the editor from it's DOM-position?

Comment: I am using version 4.9.6. There are no errors in console. When i switch tab to visual. It doesn't change. But when i close the dialog and reopen it, the tab visual will be selected.@JeffreyvanRossum

Comment: Is the editor in the dialog right away, or is it added later?

Comment: added at the time of page load right after dialog initilization@JeffreyvanRossum

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172420/discussion-between-jeffrey-van-rossum-and-melvin).